# Symfony 4.4 how to configure controllers without autowiring

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I need to inject service to controller constructor method

service.yaml

```
imports:
    - { resource: controllers.yaml }

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: false
        autoconfigure: false 
        public: false

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Application/Message,Infrastructure/Repository/MySql/Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

controllers.yaml

```
    app.controller:
        class: App\UI\Controller\AppController
        arguments:
            - '@monolog.logger.api'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    app.controller.keyword:
        class: App\UI\Controller\BlogController
        arguments:
            - '@monolog.logger.api'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

BlogController.php

```
class BlogController extends AbstractController
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function postForSubscribers(Request $request, FindPostQuery $query): JsonResponse
    {
        $page = $request->query->get('page') ?? 1;
        $limit = $request->query->get('limit') ?? 500;
        $daysBack = $request->query->get('days-back') ?? '7';
        try {
            $results = $query->getResults($daysBack, new Paging((int)$page, (int)$limit));
            return new JsonResponse($results->normalize());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->warning($e->getMessage(), [
                'line' => $e->getLine(),
                'file' => $e->getFile(),
                'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString(),
            ]);
            return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Something broken, cant fetch post data.'], 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Action `postForSubscribers` return `The controller for URI "/api/v1/post/subscribers" is not callable. Controller "App\UI\Controller\BlogController" cannot be fetched from the container because it is private. Did you forget to tag the service with "controller.service_arguments"?`

But controllers.yaml contains controller tags, how I should configure my controllers instead? 
Anyone can help?

PS. When I add to service.yaml:

```
App\UI\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/UI/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

I get: `Too few arguments to function App\UI\Controller\BlogController::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/var/cache/dev/ContainerV9lwkz0/getBlogControllerService.php on line 13 and exactly 1 expected`

Comment: To start with, the _defaults section need to be duplicated in each service.yaml file.  Probably have other issues as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I have also 8 different imported yaml files `commands`, `queries`, `repositories` etc. Everything excluding controllers works perfect.

Comment: In your original controllers.yaml file, replace the 'app.controller' id with the controller class name and set public: true.  As well as excluding your controllers from your default services.yaml as mentioned below.

Comment: And while off-topic, if you really have that many files then makeyourself a config/services directory and add a line to Kernel.php to load any files in that directory.  Eliminates the need for importing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see you didn't exclude your controller from default configuration, add the exclusion here:

```
exclude: '../src/{Application/Message,Infrastructure/Repository/MySql/Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

Its not necessary but this could override your manual configuration. (It depends which is first).

Then, focus on `autowire` parameter, if this parameter is false you have to inject dependency manually using `arguments` - see [autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html) and [service container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#manually-wiring-arguments).

Good luck!